# jQuery keep old value and add new in newline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working as a select Make, Model and Year.

Year showing based on make and model values are coming based on year.

here is a screen shot.

[image]

I want when check value it will append above check box for e.g

When I select make optioin **"PRI"** , Year 2005  and values of **"Model"** is **"PRIMODE, Temp pri** " then after I select Make option **"Yamaha**" , year 2006 and values of model FZ1 it'll appear to the next line and keep old (make option PRI value) and so and...

like [image]

Here is my code .

HTML

```
<div id="make_parent" style="font-size:15px"></div>
```

jQuery script

```
<script>
        var checked, checkedValues = new Array();
        //var iCnt = 0;
        var newhtml = '';
        var status = 'true';
        jQuery(document).on("change", "input[type=checkbox]", function(e) {
                var  str = '';
                var existhtml;

                    jQuery("#frame .model_val").each(function() {

                        if(jQuery(this).prop('checked') === true){
                            str =  str + jQuery(this).val()+' ,';
                        }
                        str1 = str.slice(0, -1);
                             newhtml = '<div class="make_'+jQuery("#mec_make").val()+'">'+jQuery("#mec_make").val()+'<div class="year_'+jQuery("#car_year_select").val()+'">'+jQuery("#car_year_select").val()+'<div class="model">'+str1+'</div></div></div>';


                    });

                    jQuery("#make_parent div").each(function (index, element) 
                    {
                        if(jQuery(element).hasClass('make_'+jQuery("#mec_make").val())) {
                            status = 'false';

                            jQuery('.make_'+jQuery("#mec_make").val() + " div").each(function (index1, element1) 
                            {   //alert('fd');  
                                if(jQuery(element1).hasClass('year_'+jQuery("#car_year_select").val())) {
                                    jQuery('.year_'+jQuery("#car_year_select .model").val()).append(str1);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //alert('make_'+jQuery("#mec_make").val()+"-- year_"+jQuery("#car_year_select").val());
                                    jQuery('.make_'+jQuery("#mec_make").val()).append('<div class="year_'+jQuery("#car_year_select").val()+'">'+jQuery("#car_year_select").val()+'<div class="model">'+str1+'</div></div>');
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            existhtml = jQuery('#make_parent').html();

                            jQuery("#make_parent").html(existhtml+newhtml);
                        }
                    });

                    if(status == 'true')
                    {
                        existhtml = jQuery('#make_parent').html();                  
                            jQuery("#make_parent").html(existhtml+newhtml);
                    }                   

        });
        </script>
```

I tried to doing by above code but it's not working as I want, it's showing repeated all times.

I want output like..

[image]

and so and so..

Comment: Wheres the php part?

Comment: i have not mention php part on above because of First i need value then i'll store in database using php but first i need value that i mentioned above.

Comment: if your question doesn't relate to php then please don't tag it with php, further more, please only post ***one*** issue per question, do not update the question to include another question but post a new one instead.